# TypeError: Cannot call property getEncoder in object

Tags: javascript, base64, encode, sha256, rhino

I am trying to encode byte array using java package Base64 in a javascript. Javascript engine is Rhino.

Below is the error in logs.

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: javax.script.ScriptException: TypeError: Cannot call property getEncoder in object [JavaPackage java.util.Base64]. It is not a function, it is "object".
```

Below is the snippet of code.

```
var md = java.security.MessageDigest.getInstance('SHA-256');
md.update(salt);
var sha256Bytes = []
sha256Bytes=md.digest(new java.lang.String(givenPassword).getBytes('UTF-8'));
var sha256Hash = java.lang.String(java.util.Base64.getEncoder().encode(sha256Bytes));
```

I am not able to figure out the issue here. Also, the package java.util.Base64.* is imported.

Comment: Which version of Rhino do you use and how do you start the script? I just tested it (Rhino-1.7.14.jar) and it works fine for me, gives me a Base64 encoded string as a result.

Comment: I am using JS Script Engine: Rhino 1.7.13

Comment: You did not mention how you start the script.  I tested with a Rhina-1.7.14 jar downloaded from [here](https://jar-download.com/?search_box=rhino)

Comment: I am restricted by the version. Only supports Rhino 1.7.13

Comment: did you solve this?

Comment: Yes. So, I imported class java.util.Base64$Encoder. Earlier I was importing it in java.util.Base64.Encoder . Not sure how $ makes a difference comparing to a '.' . But , I assume that my application imports static class in this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I imported class java.util.Base64$Encoder. Earlier I was importing it in java.util.Base64.Encoder . Not sure how $ makes a difference comparing to a '.' . But , I assume that my application imports static class in this way.